# 3D python import error

Tags: python-2.7, netbeans

I installed Netbeans and Python IDE 2.7.1 as instructed in the standard installation guide. I would like to run the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], [30, 20, 10, 0]):
     xs = np.arange(20)
     ys = np.random.rand(20)
     ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=c, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

After running the code, I am getting the following error message:

```
ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
```

Also, for almost all programs I have tested, I get the same import error message.

Could someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

With this description it seems that you have an installation problem at hand. Questions:

- can you import `matplotlib` at all (you may, e.g., try to `import matplotlib` and see if that throws an error)
- if you can import `matplotlib`, what does `matplotlib.__version__` say?
- which OS, which python (`import sys; print sys.version`)

First guess is that you do not have `matplotlib` installed in a way your interpreter would find it.

Comment: I tested again the following code:  import cvxopt
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers

    A = matrix([[1., -1.], [1., 2.]])
    c = matrix([-1., -1.])
    b = matrix([2., 8.])
    sol=solvers.lp(c,A.T,b)
    print(sol['x'])

Here is the output:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Star/Documents/Experiments/Test/src/T1.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cvxopt import matrix, solvers
ImportError: cannot import name matrix